# Using index with large key_len

Tags: mysql

I was trying to optimize my query as I saw it pop up on my slow query log. I am not completely sure I understand what I am saying, but when I ran explain on my MYSQL query it showed me something like this.

```
+------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table                    | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                       | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | subject                  | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                      | 1144 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | asset                    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | cool2                                     | 1    | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | asset_type               | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | cool                                      | 1    | Using where |
+------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

When I added an index on one of the fields, and ran explain on the query, I got:

```
+------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table                    | type   | possible_keys                       | key                                 | key_len | ref                                       | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | subject                  | ref    | new_index                           | new_index                           | 503     | const                                     | 1    | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | asset                    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY                             | 4       | cool2                                     | 1    | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | asset_type               | eq_ref | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY                             | 4       | cool                                      | 1    | Using where |
+------+-------------+--------------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Can anyone please explain to me what is the trade-off between rows and key_len. Does a big key_len make a difference? Do I have a big key_len?

Comment: *what is the trade-off between rows and key_len* Direct relation is absent.

Comment: Please provide (edit the question) the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE subject\G`.

Comment: Welcome to dba.stackexchange.com  We can better answer your questions, if you could post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE subject; - Have a great day.

Comment: Hello. I will do as soon as possible. I did not have access over the weekend.

Comment: Need to see the query, too.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the differences between the two `EXPLAINs`...

```
ALL  NULL       NULL   1144
REF  new_index  const     1
```

The first looked at ALL 1144 (approximate) rows of the table

The second used `new_index`, checking against a "constant", finding 1 (approximate) row.  Clearly faster.

The `503` may be 2+3*167, Perhaps the column is `VARCHAR(167) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL`?  The "2" is overhead for "VAR"; the "3" is the max byte length of a utf8 character.  About the only use for "503" is exactly what I just did -- deduce something about the index in question.

Or maybe it is a `VARCHAR(125) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL`?  2+4*125+1; the "1" is for a `NULL` flag.

The size of the "key_len" does not matter, except that there are limits -- 767, 3072, and possibly others, depending on version, etc.

Index "prefixing" (as danblack mentioned) is problematic.  It is often not used when you think it should.  I recommend avoiding it in most cases.  This is a case where you might need it, assuming you can't shrink the `TEXT` column:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
    foo TEXT NOT NULL, ...
    INDEX(foo(167)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`key_len` is how much of the index that is being used. For 503 I assume its a varbinary/varchar column completely/mostly(in size) indexed.

For varbinary/char columns you can limit the index amount to what normally limits the query to a minimal number of rows (how many chacters until you have only a few entries). This reduces the index size and therefore the amount of buffer pool/key cache dedicated to this and the amount of IO to load the index from disk.